# i have problem with android studio key store

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Key was created with errors:

```
Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. 
It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format 
using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore 
C:\Users\Development\mykeystove.keystore -destkeystore 
C:\Users\Development\mykeystove.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12".
```

Comment: this is just a warning which recommend you to use the standard format rather than the `.keysore` format.

Comment: after that when i generate signed apk i got errors

Comment: _It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format 
using `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore`_ I think it is pretty clear about what to do

Comment: But if I do as it said, in Android studio while signing the app I am getting error as follows: Algorithm HmacPBESHA256 not available.

I have created keys from AOSP code.